# How to disable popup when user taps phone number in WKWebView on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, wkwebview

When user taps phone number in `WKWebView`, popup appears:

[image]

How can I intercept such taps and perform a custom action?

On iPhone, I can intercept taps on phone numbers with `WKNavigationDelegate` method:

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                    decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
                    decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    //....
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

however on iPad the popup just appears and delegate method is not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could imagine several approaches, though I don't have the opportunity to try them right now.

## WKWebViewConfiguration

- Set properties like `dataDetectorTypes` to `.none`, although that should be the default, anyway.
- Use `setURLSchemeHandler(_:forURLScheme:)` to ignore the `tel://` scheme

## HTML/JS

- Remove the offending link tags before displaying the HTML through scraping
- Apply some Javascript that catches the event and use `preventDefault()` or something.